# Can there be quantum spin liquids in 1D?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin, field-theory

It seems like everyone studies quantum spin liquids in either 2D or 3D. Can not there be quantum spin liquids in 1D?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "quantum spin liquid".

Comment: @NorbertSchuch in my perspective, QSL is a state which keeps fluctuating even at T = 0 and it has very high degree of entanglement.

Comment: From that definition, perhaps you would consider the spin-1/2 (or 3/5, 5/2, ...) Heisenberg chain to be a spin liquid? It does not have spin order at T=0, and it has entanglement that grows logarithmically with the entanglement cut.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt Maybe "gapped" in another criterion?

Comment: @LuqmanSaleem What about the AKLT chain?  --  Note that we generally expect any *gapped* system to have the same (area-law) amount of entanglement, unless you are talking about the prefactor!

Comment: The AKLT chain (and the odd-integer-spin Heisenberg chains) fit nicely into the definition of symmetry-procted topological (SPT) phases of matter, which are often distinguished from spin liquids and other phases with "intrinsic topological order." If we insist on a spin liquid being a gapped phase whose ground states are described by a topological QFT, I *think* that this is impossible in one dimension, but I admit I do not know for sure. Otherwise I'd probably try to write up an answer.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt Depends whether "topological" is part of your definition of "spin liquid".  I'd argue a spin liquid is a spin system which does not exhibit long-range order, which doesn't require it to be topological.  It is true, however, that "spin liquid" is often used synonymous with "topological spin liquid".